# Why Instagram API media search gives photos located in rectangle

Tags: gis, instagram, instagram-api

I was collecting some photos from certain locations with Instagram media search API. 
In API query you have to give the location center point (lat, lng) and radius. 
When I was applying the photos on map then I saw that all the photos are located in a rectangle what is taller in North-South direction.

Could somebody please explain why it gives rectangle instead of circle?
And why not to give a square?

Comment: Might be a bit off topic for StackOverflow. Anyhow I guess it has to do with faster selects on square/rectangular spaces in databases. As for why rectangular over square, maybe expected "screen" sizes of phones. No need to get anything that is unlikely to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I was also thinking that it might be easier to get results in square/rectangle. But odd is that I asked radius 5km and the rectangle came 20km N-S direction and 10km to E-W direction. For screens - yes, we are mostly using phones what are in portrait view but when it is in landscape view in this case there will be several photos to hide behind the screen.